# Stripe returns a "No such token" error (Plaid Integration)

Tags: plaid

I am getting this error from Stripe when I try to create a new source for the selected bank account. I am using the new (beta) version of the Plaid Node SDK. Here is my code:

```
let user;
const mode = "sandbox";
const dsService = new CaspioDsService();

// Load the user if not already loaded by cognitoAuth
if (!req.user) {
  user = new User(
    dsService,
    new CaspioRefDataService(),
    new AuthUserService({
      organizationId: res.locals.organization.Organization_ID,
      isAuthenticated: res.locals.isAuthenticated,
    })
  );
  await user.load(req.params.userId);
} else {
  user = req.user.userObject;
}

const configuration = new Configuration({
  basePath: PlaidEnvironments[mode],
  baseOptions: {
    headers: {
      "PLAID-CLIENT-ID": config.plaid.clientId,
      "PLAID-SECRET": mode === "sandbox" ? config.plaid.secretSandbox : config.plaid.secretProduction,
      "Plaid-Version": "2020-09-14",
    },
  },
});

const plaidClient = new PlaidApi(configuration);
console.log(configuration.basePath);  // https://sandbox.plaid.com

// Exchange the public token for the Plaid access token
const plaidTokenRes = await plaidClient.itemPublicTokenExchange({
  public_token: req.body.publicToken,
});
const accessToken = plaidTokenRes.data.access_token;
console.log(accessToken); // access-sandbox-d92396c2-1f49-4780-9ae9-23d50645f364

// Get the Stripe bank account token from Plaid
const stripeTokenRes = await plaidClient.processorStripeBankAccountTokenCreate({
  access_token: accessToken,
  account_id: req.body.accountId
});
const bankAccountToken = stripeTokenRes.data.stripe_bank_account_token;
console.log(bankAccountToken);  // btok_1JFMGwGq7ejZoSiwGmM8WSSm

let stripeCustomerId = user.getStripeToken();
const stripeClient = await StripeHelper.getStripeClient(mode); // Get Stripe client in sandbox mode
console.log(stripeCustomerId); // cus_Jt7AWZjC8rHPzt

// Add the source to the Stripe customer and get the bank account info
const bankAccount = await stripeClient.customers.createSource(stripeCustomerId, {
  source: bankAccountToken,
}); // Error: No such token: 'btok_1JFMGwGq7ejZoSiwGmM8WSSm'
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? I expect the issue is with my code, or possibly Plaid (I don't think it is a Stripe problem).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting a token from Plaid, but Stripe is rejecting it, which suggests a problem with the relationship between your Plaid and Stripe setups. Are you sure that you enabled the Plaid/Stripe integration in the Plaid dashboard and that the client id / secret you're using matches the Plaid account where the integration is enabled? The Plaid docs also suggest that this error can be caused by using a mismatched set of environments (e.g. using Production with Stripe but Sandbox with Plaid).

Comment: Thanks Alex. Yes, the integration is showing as "on" in Plaid and I am definitely using keys from the same Plaid account (it's the only one I have). I also saw the docs about a mis-match of prod and staging, but I'm pretty sure both Plaid and Stripe are using staging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that we had the wrong Stripe account connected. Silly one, but I'm posting this in case anyone else makes the same mistake.